# Attempting to list all product categories and the price range of all products within them

Tags: plugins, php, functions

I'm trying to display a list of all product categories and the price range of the products within those categories.

E.g

**Headwear – £30-£150**

**Shoes – £35-£300**

Where "Headwear" is the Product Category Name, "£30" is the lowest price of a product within that category and "£150" is the highest.

So far I have used the following code to list the categories, but not sure how to check for products within each and get the prices etc.

```
$order = 'asc';
$hide_empty = false ;
$cat_args = array(
    'orderby'    => $orderby,
    'order'      => $order,
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
);
 
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $cat_args );
 
if( !empty($product_categories) ){
    echo '
 
<ul>';
    foreach ($product_categories as $key => $category) {
        echo '
 
<li>';
        echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($category).'" >';
        echo $category->name;
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>
 
 
';
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've asked this on the woocommerce support forum but no responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can get using SQL query -

```
global $wpdb;
 $results = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT pm.meta_value
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships as t
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy as tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms as t ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON tr.object_id = pm.post_id
        WHERE tt.taxonomy LIKE 'product_cat'
        AND t.term_id = {$term->term_id}
        AND pm.meta_key = '_price'
    ");

    sort($results, SORT_NUMERIC);
print_r($results);
```